# Fake radio button 1 option only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to simulate the behavior of a radio button but using, instead of and input tag, an span, in order to be easier to style with css. I can simulate the change of state, but I cannot figure out how to only let one button to be selected.

Here is my js for the 'change of state':

```
function CheckRadioButton() {
    $(".radio-button").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
            $(this).removeClass('checked');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('checked');
        }
    });
}
```

What I'd like to do is, if one button changes its class to selected, all the rest have to be 'unselected'.

Another problem I encounter is that I have several "categories" in which I use this type of buttons and I only want the only option inside of each category. For example:

```
<p class="fake-label">Skirt</p>
            <div class="radio-button-wrapper">
                <span class="radio-button"></span>
                <span>Yes</span>
            </div>
            <div class="radio-button-wrapper">
                <span class="radio-button"></span>
                <span>No</span>
            </div>

<p class="fake-label">Season</p>
                <div class="radio-button-wrapper">
                    <span class="radio-button"></span>
                    <span>Summer</span>
                </div>
                <div class="radio-button-wrapper">
                    <span class="radio-button"></span>
                    <span>Winter</span>
                </div>
```

How can I do to be able to 'choose' only one between yes/no and only one between 'summer/winter', but both at the same time?? (only two of this for spans can have class 'checked' at the same time)

Thank you :)

Comment: This is a bad idea. Accessibility will almost certainly suffer. If you need radio button functionality, then use radio buttons. Everything else does not make much sense. _Hiding_ those actual input elements from the user, and providing them with different elements to _control_ those radio buttons, would be a different issue. Approaches and explanations for that are easy enough to find out there.

Comment: I suggest that you put them in some sort of group, so you can better identify which radio belongs to which. E.g. in pseudo: foreach radio in current.parent.

Comment: Ok, but it is not my development, I have to adjust to it. It sucks, I know, but I can't help it. Is there any possible way to do it?

Comment: Then maybe you have to search through the previous and following elements, check if they are radios and set the state.

Comment: If it's not your development, the developer who did it did a bad job. I would honestly think about writing some javascript to convert that markup into real inputs (if I don't have access to the markup, of course), and then use my answer posted below.

Comment: mi idea es que puedes tener un arreglo que mantenga los estados y solo permitirías que hubiese uno en `true`. Hope it helps!

Comment: English please, and that's still a bad idea. Marta Lobo do you have any possibility to change the original HTML?

Comment: I don´t know, I'll ask on Monday ;)

Comment: Nice, if they allow you to change it, please write here again so we can help further if you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mfzeas3r/)

Yo can add an additional div to group similar categories and update your jquery code like below.

**HTML**

```
<p class="fake-label">Skirt</p>
<div class="radio-group">
            <div class="radio-button-wrapper">
                <span class="radio-button"></span>
                <span>Yes</span>
            </div>
            <div class="radio-button-wrapper">
                <span class="radio-button"></span>
                <span>No</span>
            </div>
</div>
<p class="fake-label">Season</p>
<div class="radio-group">
                <div class="radio-button-wrapper">
                    <span class="radio-button"></span>
                    <span>Summer</span>
                </div>
                <div class="radio-button-wrapper">
                    <span class="radio-button"></span>
                    <span>Winter</span>
                </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
 $(".radio-button").click(function () {        
             $(this).closest('div.radio-group').find(".radio-button").removeClass('checked');  
             $(this).addClass('checked');               
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the power of real inputs with the freedom of using other tags:

```css
.input-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label {
    padding-left: 22px;
}

input[type="radio"] + label:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left:3px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #bada55;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="radio" name="test" id="option1" checked><label for="option1">Option1</label>
</div>
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="radio" name="test" id="option2"><label for="option2">Option1</label>
</div>
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="radio" name="test" id="option3"><label for="option3">Option1</label>
</div>
```

It's kind like adding/removing classes like you did in your example, but instead we use the `:checked + label` selector to select the label of the currently checked input, that way we have the accessibility of real inputs (almost) and the freedom of writing our markup the way we want it to be.
And the best thing is this solution is css only and it can be used to hide/show entire sections of a page.

PS: I said "almost" the same accessibility because I think some screen readers will ignore inputs with `display: none`, to fix this you can still use:

```
position: absolute;
left: -99999px;
```

EDIT: Since it seams you really want to go down this fake-inputs, this should help:

```
$(".radio-button").click(function () {
    $(".radio-button").removeClass('checked);
    $(this).addClass('checked');
});
```

Comment: But here you are not using other tags, you are using <input>

Comment: That's the whole point of it, hide the real input and create your own, using the browser's default functionality for checking/unchecking. Use real input but be free to style like if you didn't. It's a really bad idea to fake radio boxes. I read in your comments above that you didn't write the html, I suggest you rewrite it if you can. If you can't I honestly would convert their html into real inputs using javascript. The one who decided to use fake inputs made a really bad choice.

Comment: I'm kinda new in this so I can't really take sides in this... But how could I change this spans into inputs with js??

Comment: That's a little bit more complicated and out of topic. I updated my answer to include what you're asking for, but I still think it would be better to change the source HTML.